# Volumetric Shade coming out ultra low resolusion

Tags: volumetrics

any ideas why my Volumetric shader is doing this to the monkey? Thanks a lot :)!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just seeing that this is an evee vs cycles thing. Is it possible to get decent fog details in evee?

Comment: Well, you didn't show your settings, but generally speaking you can get more details by using a smaller _Tile Size_ and more _Samples_ in the _Render Properties_ > _Volumetrics_ options. However this won't change the volume to match the shape of Suzanne. Quoting from the Blender manual about _Eevee Limitiations_: _"**Volume Objects** - Object volume shaders will affect the whole bounding box of the object. The shape of the volume must be adjusted using procedural texturing inside the shader."_ So in _Eevee_ the volumetrics always have the cuboid shape of the bounding box (where density > 0).